# Is it a player's whole turn if they are chosen for a Showdown?

Tags: uno

If I play a showdown card and play against the person next to me, what happens after the showdown? Does the person I challenged still get their turn, or was the showdown their turn?

Answer (score 2):

I've never played this game, but I've now read the rules pdf [from here](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/GKC04-Eng.pdf)

I couldn't find anything in the rules that indicated when the next player would start their turn!  I can only assume passing a turn works in the same way as [basic Uno rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf), where play passes clockwise after a player plays a card.

The rules for showdowns say

> The player who played the card takes the Showdown unit and places it
> between themselves and the next player in the current order of play
> (unless they played a Wild Showdown Card – more on that later).

the Wild Showdown Card is then expanded on later with

> When you play this card, you get to choose which player to have a
> showdown with

There is nothing in these rules which indicates that taking part in a showdown is the target player's whole turn.  It seems to me that a showdown just happens with the next player in turn order, who then takes their turn afterwards as normal.

If it *was* the next player's whole turn I would expect the rules for a wild showdown to suggest play continue from the player chosen for the wild showdown, but they do not.

As a general rule for games, if something is not stated clearly in the rules then it almost certainly is not a rule.